# String American Megatrend Laptop keeps on getting BSOD

Tags: bsod

after days of installing windows 11 on my laptop having an AMD 2700U processor  I tried installing offline enrol to windows insider build and I received updates at first everything works well but on the third update the laptop keeps on receiving BsOD so I tried to fix by resetting the laptop but unfortunately after resetting the laptop it keeps on getting bSod and does not recognized bootable device as I tried reformatting using a bootable device. please help me.
The stopcode error is 0xa0000001

Comment: https://www.minitool.com/news/0xa0000001.html     ......  Update all your drivers and BIOS

Comment: How to update? I can't access to windows instead I keep on getting bSod error

Comment: Does your computer (manufacturer) have a Driver Update App?   That is how I update drivers.

Comment: I think yes but I need to log in to windows but how? I can't even access the log in menu instead after the boot it directly prompted the BsOd error and I tried creating bootable usb however it can't be detected and I tried to set up in the Bios looking for Usb boot but there's none

Comment: I also have another harddisk which windows 10 is installed however it can't be recognized hut on other pc it can.

Comment: See if the Updater can be put on a bootable USB Key. I have seen this before.

Comment: The laptop don't recognized the usb

Comment: It sounds like this board is a brick and apparently not recoverable.

Comment: Are there no other solution?

Comment: Probably not.  You can take the board to a repair shop to see if they can get it going.

Comment: I think there something in the Bios setup because when I plug in my external harddrive where I installed windows 10 it has led light on but still there were no option in the Bios boot menu to boot the drive. Lately when I plug it in the system read it and was able to load windows 10. Now I just don't know why all of a sudden it can't be recognized. I already disabled secure boot and enabled the Csm.

Comment: Both of your comments should be added to the question, not a comment in response to a specific comment based question.  This will help future people find the problem they are looking for.

Comment: I also have no idea what a "String American Megatrend Laptop" is.. but I probably have a good guess.

Comment: “I already disabled secure boot and enabled the CSM” - Windows 11 doesn’t support Legacy mode, so disable CSM, and you really shouldn’t disable Secure Boot but that’s optional. Booting in UEFI mode isn’t

Comment: I tried but still won't help. I tried the usb to boot on other pc and works fine but on my laptop it can't be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor AMD Ryzen 7 2700U is not compatible with Windows 11.

I don't know what went wrong and how you have tried to force-install
Windows 11, but I suggest that you try to install back Windows 10
from scratch (meaning reformat the disk).

If you have any important data on the disk and no backups,
boot a Live Linux USB to copy your data, before formatting the disk.

If Windows 10 similarly BSODs, the problem might be in hardware,
so the best way is to use a professional repair-shop.

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but the OP says it will not boot with USB.  I suggested the same thing.

Comment: @John: If we had some more info about what boot media he's using, we could give more specific advice. I also think that he is probably now at my last paragraph.

Comment: I'm using sandisk efi bootable device and created it through rufus. I have installed windows 11 without secure boot and I have also disable TPM 2 which is available in the option and was able to run and received updates on windows 11 however when I tried installing windows insider build (dev) after the update when the laptop restart I get green screen so I tried resetting but after the reset. Only BsOd error and I can't even access the login menu and can't even reformat it because the usb is not recognize in the boot menu

Comment: I repeat that it's not a good idea to install a crippled version of Windows 11 on your computer, rather than a fully functional Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to install Windows 10 but still there's no option in boot menu to boot in usb.